# Difference between MapBox mbtiles and offline mbtiles for MapBox Android SDK

Tags: mapbox, android, sqlite

I know what have some difference between MapBox mbtiles and offline mbtiles for MapBox Android SDK.

In offline  mbtiles for SDK besides tiles contains:

Style JSON.
All fonts and icons associated with the style.
TileJSON for all sources.
Map tiles covering the geographic area of the offline regions.

Then all this is Packed in sqlite, but according to what scheme?

MapBox mbtiles  have spec:
https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/
https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1

But i cant find some spec for offline packege.

Answer (score 0):

None of the mapbox SDK support mbtiles. You must host you data and take it offline with their API. You can not load your own Mbtiles

Comment: Thats not true. You can host your own local server on the device and show local mbtiles from there. Im not commenting on the affectiveness or safeness of this approach, but just to the fact that it is possible. https://gist.github.com/typebrook/7d25be326f0e9afd58e0bbc333d2a175

Comment: adding a localhost:portnumber/{z}/{x}/{y}.png or .pbf is just that a URL not an mbtiles.MapBox Does not support MBTILES or GPKG. It supports a URL

Comment: We've added tile server to our MapBox GL Native projects and it's very efficient and effective. we've also removed Telemetry instead of users manually opting out.  You can find other mapping libraries that natively support MBTILES and GPKG without tile server. Like WhirlyGlobe and Tangram ES.  We use OpenMapTiles OpenStreet Map Vector Tiles with MapBox instead of MapBox Streets. Because easier to have the data in mbtiles and have it pre-staged for different areas than using API

Answer (score 0):

The schemas outlined are meant to be followed as interfaces. SQLite views that produce compatible results may be used instead. For convenience, this specification refers to tables and virtual tables (views) as tables.

See [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md)